# Matlab: What is the proper way to calculate mean square error for complex numbers

Tags: matlab, self-study, complex

I am confused regarding the calculation of mean square error involving complex numbers. Considering, the true channel coefficients to be

```
h_true =

   0.7071 + 0.7071i
   0.4243 + 0.4243i
   0.2121 + 0.2121i
```

and the estimates to be

```
 h_e1 = 0.8100+0.8100i  
 h_e2 = 0.5100 + 0.5100i  
 h_e3 =  0.1200 +  0.1200i;
```

For training epoch 1, I calculated the error between the estimates and the actual  as

```
e = ((h_e1 - h_true(1)).^2) + ((h_e2 - h_true(2)).^2) + ((h_e3 - h_true(3)).^2)   ;
```

Then the mean square error is

```
mse = e/3;
```

which gives zero for the real part and some small number for the imaginary part.

```
mse = 0 + 0.0176i
```

Should I be calculating the error separetely for iamginary and real part or is this okay?

Comment: you should magnitude-square the differences: `e = (abs(h_e1 - h_true(1)).^2) + (abs(h_e2 - h_true(2)).^2) + (abs(h_e3 - h_true(3)).^2);`
if you're doing this in a lower level language, then $$ |z|^2 = \Re\{z\}^2 + \Im\{z\}^2 $$ and the square root operation needed for the `abs()` function can be skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean square error is

```
e = ((abs(h_e1 - h_true(1))^2) + (abs(h_e2 - h_true(2))^2) + (abs(h_e3 - h_true(3))^2))/3;
```

But it is tediuos!

What if you had $1000$ terms instead of $3$? Do you want to add one by one?

Do it in the vector form for more clarity and ease of implementation:

$$\mathrm{mse}=\mathsf{E}(|\mathbf{h}-\hat{\mathbf{h}}|^2)$$

In MATLAB, you can use the function `mse()`

```
 h_true = [ 0.7071 + 0.7071i
            0.4243 + 0.4243i
            0.2121 + 0.2121i ];

 h_e = [ 0.8100 + 0.8100i  
         0.5100 + 0.5100i  
         0.1200 + 0.1200i ];

 e = mean(abs(h_e-h_true).^2); % or eqivalently e = mse(abs(h_e-h_true));
```

Comment: Thank you for the ansawer. I have a related question would you please help? The channel coefficients are modelled as L = 3;
H = (randn(L, 1) + 1j*randn(L,1))/sqrt(2);
 and my input data $x$ also has real and imaginary part. The received data is $z = filter(H,1, y)$ where $y = x + w$ where w is additive white complex noise $~ N(0,\sigma^2_w)$. I am using Uscented Kalman filter for estimating the channel coefficients. Would I do the estimation separately for real and imaginary part?

Comment: I am confused because if I do the estimation using both real and imaginary then what would be the covariance matrix $P$ -- would it contain real and imag? What is the correct way to do estimation and implementation of it. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Should I do filtering/ processing with separated real/imag data rather then complex if the underling data is complex? Filtering separately is easier as I don't have to modify the underlying equations and the matlab implementations avaliable but I wonder if this is theoretically correct or not.

Comment: @SKM You are posing several questions and I am afraid It cannot be handled in the comments, why not asking a separate question? Explain the situation in details and I will try to answer if I have relevant information.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson It wasn't the main point! The idea was to do it the right way, which is the vector way...

Comment: I have posted a separate question for the problems that I mentioned in the comments earlier. The link to it is http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/35820/how-to-prevent-covariance-matrix-p-to-grow-exponentially-for-complex-data Thank you for help

Comment: What about the error for imaginary part? if we do it altogether than how we will estimate the error for imaginary part?